# NSString to C-style char array crashes on second invoke to drawRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to write text using a Core Graphics context. I can do it the first time, no problem, but the second time crashes my iPhone app. Here is a code snippet:

```
NSString *name = [MyClass getName];
const char *cname = [name UTF8String];
[self drawText:context text:cname];
```

`MyClass` and `drawText` are custom classes/methods but you get the idea. These three lines live in `drawRect:`

The first time `drawRect:` is executed, I see the text as expected. However, on *any* refresh of drawRect:, the line:

```
const char *cname = [name UTF8String];
```

causes my app to crash with the cryptic, `"GDB: Program loaded."` status message.

I get a similar response even when I use the `getCString:` method.  I think I might be missing a fundamental understanding of NSString to char array conversion.

Comment: I'm too new to this post so I can't rate the responders.  However, they were correct in that I was dereferencing a released object.  I made the NSString a global variable (which is fine since reallocating it for each drawRect: seemed inefficient anyway).  Essentially I ended up removing the first line and everything works as expected.  Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to accept one of the answers as the correct one, even if you can't moderate them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to call methods on an object which has been deallocated already.  The [`UTF8String`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) message has the problem that you can't hold onto the returned pointer, since it may become invalidated when the string is released -- you have to copy the string if you need to hold onto it.  However, `getCString:maxLength:encoding:` does not have that problem.

Make sure you're following properly memory management protocol.  See the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), and double-check that you're sending `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` messages to the proper objects at the proper times.  Chances are you're sending an extra `release` or `autorelease` when you shouldn't be, or you're forgetting to `retain` your string somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that you're keeping a reference to the previously returned char* and you are dereferencing it on the second call. According to spec, the pointer is not valid to store: [The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is created.](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String)